# How to implement code to multiple classes in Java?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have *two* classes: JDialog and JFrame (see below). Now I want them to get some extra functionality, but I want the two classes both to extend my code, without writing the code twice. Is there a way to do that?

```
java.awt.Window » java.awt.Dialog » javax.swing.JDialog  
java.awt.Window » java.awt.Frame » javax.swing.JFrame
```

(PS: Actually, I want to "rewrite" the source code of `java.awt.Window`, adding extra functionality. I know that's not possible, but that would be a "solution", because if I do so, both JDialog and JFrame would extend my brand new methods.)

**Example:**
Suppose I want to add the method `moveWindowToMagicPositionOnScreen()`, moving the window to a user-friendly position on the screen—I know, it's just an example. I want the method to apply to both `JDialog` and `JFrame`. Using inheritance, I must write two classes, for example `MagicJDialog` and `MagicJFrame`, each implementing the method `moveWindowToMagicPositionOnScreen()` in exactly the same manner. Well, that's pretty redundant. So I don't want to have the code written twice. In some way, I want *one* class to use the code of the other class.

Comment: Have you considered composition?

Comment: PS: You should provide an example of what you seek...

Comment: *Terminology:* you're not "rewriting" the source code of `java.awt.Window`, you're overriding it in your class (assuming there's nothing final in there preventing you from doing that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface / delegate / composition ideas are probably the "cleanest".  But an acceptable and arguably simpler alternative is to make a utility class with a static method.

```
public static moveWindowToMagicPositionOnScreen(Window window) {
  // calculate new x and y
  window.setLocation(x, y);  // or perhaps setBounds()...
}
```

In practice, I'd probably put the calculation logic into another method, `computeMagicPositionOnScreen`().  If it makes sense (it may not) this static utility class could actually be a "real" (non-static) class, say MagicPositionCalculator, that might have multiple instances, say one per each screen, one for really large screens, one for power-users, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Java does not support mixins. The easiest and clearest approach to take here would be to use composition, in which case you only have to write the wrappers twice, but the actual implementation lives in a single location.

Answer (score 1):

Like several others have suggested, prefer composition over inheritance. However, you can create an common interface for your method:

```
public interface Magic {
    void moveWindowToMagicPositionOnScreen();
}
```

If the code that moves the window is *exactly* the same create a delegate class:

```
public class MagicDelegate implements Magic {

    public void moveWindowToMagicPositionOnScreen() {
        // TODO implement logic
    };
}
```

Then have your two classes implement the `Magic` interface using `MagicDelegate`:

```
public MagicJDialog implements Magic {

    private MagicDelegate magicDelegate;   // TODO instantiate

    public void moveWindowToMagicPositionOnScreen() {
        magicDelegate.moveWindowToMagicPositionOnScreen();
    }
}
```

and

```
public MagicJFrame implements Magic {

    private MagicDelegate magicDelegate;   // TODO instantiate

    public void moveWindowToMagicPositionOnScreen() {
        magicDelegate.moveWindowToMagicPositionOnScreen();
    }
}
```

Side note, the code that moves the window is only partially the same, you can either choose to ignore the `MagicDelegate` class or create a template class with the common parts:

```
public abstract MagicTemplate implements Magic {

    public moveWindowToMagicPositionOnScreen() {
        // common logic
        implementationSpecificLogic();
        // more common logic  
    }

    protected abstract void implementationSpecificMethod();
}
```

Now, the `MagicJDialog` class and the `MagicJFrame` class can extend the `MagicTemplate` class and implement the `implementationSpecificLogic()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I think you want to apply **DRY** `(Don't Repeat Yourself)` design principle and partially **LSP** `(Liskov substitution Principle)`, if you want some method to be stored in a class, and then use this method from other two classes, then I think **prefering *composing* over *inheritance* will be a good idea. Cause you will be able to use the desired method without inheriting the methods that you don't want.**